# Marklogic Roxy and Template Driven Extraction

Tags: marklogic, roxy

Does Roxy have support for deploying templates for use with Marklogic 9's Template Driven Extraction?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not built-in yet. We have a [Support for TDE](https://github.com/marklogic-community/roxy/issues/848) ticket to track the need for this. Please raise a flag there to push its priority.

You can get there fairly easily with some deploy/app_specific.rb tweaking though. You could either drop such templates in the schemas/ folder, and then run extra code afterwards to apply the correct collection. Or write code that uploads each file, and inserts them with the appropriate tde functions.

HTH!

Comment: Is there a tutorial you recommend for modifying app_specific.rb for the above modifications?

Comment: There is a general wiki page about decorating existing commands, and/or creating custom ones that way: https://github.com/marklogic-community/roxy/wiki/Adding-Custom-Build-Steps

Comment: Thanks! I'll take a look :D